# Disable Postgress App 2.5.12 Automatic Startup on Mac

Tags: macos, startup, postgresql

I have installed [postgress app 2.5.12](https://postgresapp.com/) on my mac and it automatically starts with my system boot. I have checked System Settings > General > Login Items as well as /Library/LaunchDaemons and /Library/LaunchAgents but nothing related to this app is there. How can I disable the automatic launch of this app?
I am using MacOS 13.0.1

Comment: By system boot do you actually mean login? Is the process running as root in Activity Monitor?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not just starting because it was launched when you shutdown or rebooted?  The benefit of Postgres.app is that you don't install it, it's just a self-contained executable.